# Jquery If / Else Percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 variables:

1. `$a`, the width of my navigation
2. `$b`, the `li` in my navigation

I'm looking to to make a conditional statement based on the percentage my `li` takes up in my navigation, for example:

```
  $a = $("nav").width();
  $b = $("nav li").first.width(); 

  if($b > (27% of $a)) {
    echo "<p>do something crazy</p>";
  }
  else if ($b > (87% of $a)){
    echo "<p> do something less crazy</p>";
  }
  else ($b > (47% of $a)){
    echo "<p> do nothing at all</p>";
  }
```

Can anyone explain how to compare a percentage of...?

Comment: The question is less *jQuery* related and more JavaScript mathematical operations.  Like principles of mathematics, a percentage can be written in more than one way; for instance `25% == 0.25`.  The first isn't recognized by JavaScript, the second (decimal notation) is.  There also is no `of` keyword in JavaScript, so you need to `$a * .27`, however you may need to do a `parseFloat($a)` depending on whether your version of `jQuery.width()` returns in `px` or not.

Comment: Looked it up and `width()` does not include the unit in current versions.  Also `$` generally denotes a jQuery object variable.  In your case `width()` should return a number, not a jQuery object, so you should not use `$` sigil/prefix; however `a` and `b` are also not good variable names as they are used internally in sorting variables and bad things could happen if you use them in the wrong place.  Instead more descriptive names would be better: `var nav_width = ..., li_width = ...`

Comment: It also should be noted that `echo` in the context above is going to be a problem.  That's not javascript, and it's not even server side scripting.  Maybe you mean `document.write()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do the math yourself:

```
if($b > ($a * 0.27)) {
```

The percent sign `%` has a different meaning, it is the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators).

---

Ah, and `else (/* whatever */){` is wrong, should be just `else {`. And `echo` is PHP, not JavaScript! :-)

Comment: haha, well this is sort of embarrassing, thanks. I give you the answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comments and your code:

```
var nav_width = $("nav").width(),
    li_width  = $("nav li").first.width(); 

if ( li_width > (nav_width * 0.27) ) {
  // echo "<p>do something crazy</p>";
}
else if ( li_width > (nav_width * 0.87) ) {
  // echo "<p> do something less crazy</p>";
}
else ( li_width > (nav_width * 0.47) ) {
  // echo "<p> do nothing at all</p>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   var a=$("element").html();

    var b= $("secondelement").html();

if(a>b){}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here.